# How can I move the oldest file in a directory repeatedly using a batch script?

Tags: windows, batch

How can I move the topmost (oldest) file in a directory one by one in a batch script (Windows 7)?

I am using this script:

```
:backup
move something somewhere
timeout 36000
goto backup
```

I want to regularly move the top file in a directory to another directory. How can I specify that only the topmost (oldest) file should be moved at each turn of the script?

Comment: What does `oldest` mean? Oldest in regards to creation date or last modified date? Remember, just because you see the files in an order in Windows Explorer/File Explorer doesn't mean that order is persistent

Comment: You want PowerShell for that kind of use rather than the limited cmd processor. With PS, you could list the folder, filter to the oldest and then move it. You could even set up a file system watch for changes rather than doing a loop.

Comment: Well, let's say oldest in regard to last modified date.

Comment: I would consider using a PowerShell script instead but I would know even less how to write it as I have limited experience in PowerShell scripting. At least with batch scripting I have written or rather modified a few scripts in the past.

Comment: @Moe1: Keep in mind that having a batch file running in the background waiting for 10 hours is not a good way of doing things. Restrict the batch file to just the move operation and create a scheduled task instead to run it every 10 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### How can I move the oldest file in a directory repeatedly using a batch script?

The following batch file `test.cmd` will move the oldest file in a directory:

```
@echo off
rem parameters
rem %1 source directory
rem %2 target directory
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
:backup
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir "%1" /a-d /b /o-d') do set something=%%a
move "%1\%something%" "%2\%something%"
timeout 36000
goto backup
```

Call the batch file with parameters, for example:

```
test olddirectory newdirectory
```

Comment: I tried this but I could not figure out exactly how you mean. Could you paste the code with move implemented?

Comment: But how does it know which directory to look in? Hang on, I will write a version with an example directory.

Comment: In the same directory where the batch file resides? Let's say I want to define the directory. I know this is not correct:

Comment: @echo off
    :backup
    for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /a-d /b /o-d') do set something=%%a
    move %C:\Olddestination% C:\Newdestination\%something%
    timeout 36000
goto backup

Comment: Obviously completely incorrect. But it would be nice to be able to define the from and to directories in the script.

Comment: First trial rendered a "syntax of the command is incorrect" error. Will try again as soon as possible.

Comment: @Moe1 Apologies, there was a `\ ` in the wrong place. I've also added some `"`s so it works when there are spaces in the filenames.

Comment: Hmm... I get a file not found error.

Comment: Works. I added quotation marks to the folders specified in the script.

Comment: Thank you very much @DavidPostill :) Tested the script again with multiple files and it does indeed move them one at a time at specified intervals. Excellent : D

Comment: (Missing an e on first line I think : D)

Comment: @Karan good point :)